# Wrong date format

Tags: language-support

I know this should be really simple to solve but every link I read about changing format is solved using Language Support. I want the top bar date the format it should.

[image]

I want it to have Spanish format, i.e. "jue 24 dec", not "jue dec 24". The only thing that is spanishy about my top bar date is that it reads "jue" (from Spanish "jueves") instead of "thu".

This is the output of the `locale` command is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I know I could install Clock Override Extension, but there should be an easy way to fix this.
I did my installation in Spanish, then I changed the SO language to English.

Comment: I don't understand the question - if you want your clock to display in English format, why don't you change the Regional Format to English?

Comment: @Sebastian, I want it to have Spanish format, i.e. jue 24 dec, not jue dec 24. The only thing that is spanishy about my top bar date is that it reads "jue" (from Spanish "jueves") instead of "thu".

Comment: Okay, you should make it clear in your question that this is your problem, because it is not at all clear. But have you tried opening the properties of the clock itself and changing its format in there?

Comment: @Sabastian, I'll make it explicit in that case. I don't know what you mean by "Propieties of the clock itself" and I don't have my PC right now, but I think I haven't tried it. It probably is something as trivial as it sounds. In a few hours I'll try that, if you tell me what do you mean.

Comment: @Sebastian I use **English (UK)** regional format which has the following for the date: `Fri 25 Dec 2020 14:43:15` 
However the clock is displayed in the format:
`Fri Dec 25 14:43`
and the "clock" has nothing configurable, except "Time Format" (24-hour or AM/PM).

Comment: Alright - the clock app I use on Ubuntu Studio has a Custom Format option, so I format it as I like. Probably stock Ubuntu uses another app that doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an experiment I installed the Spanish language, opened the `~/.profile` file for editing, added this line:

```
export LANGUAGE=es
```

and re-logged in. That made a difference. The explanation is that the order of the date components is taken from the language you are using, not the selected formats. So a "solution" would be to switch to Spanish as display language for the desktop.

This appears to be a design inconsistency, and it's reported here:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789205

But as a workaround I created the file `gnome-desktop-3.0.po`:

```
msgid "%a %b %-e_%R"
msgstr "%a %-e %b_%R"
msgid "%b %-e_%R"
msgstr "%-e %b_%R"
```

Then I converted it to an `.mo` file:

```
msgfmt gnome-desktop-3.0.po -o gnome-desktop-3.0.mo
```

and saved it as:

```
/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/gnome-desktop-3.0.mo
```

Comment: The workarround seems a bit more subtle than the changing all the desktop display to Spanish. I liked it and it worked for me.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @MarcoCiafa: Subtle indeed, but it's at least a way to achieve a consistent date format, i.e. the weekday and month names as well as the order of the components as you would expect for a Spanish speaking country. Good that it proved to work for you.

Comment: I have just realised that the login screen haven't changed. Do you know if it's possible to change it as well? It's not that important thought, I'm not seeing it all the time.

Comment: @MarcoCiafa: I edited the answer with an addition which affects the login screen on my machine at least. Maybe you see the pattern now? :)

Comment: It worked, thanks. The only pattern I see is the %a, %-e, %b, _%R  apparently represent the weekday, the day, the month and the hour, but I don't have a clue about how the machine knows you were referring to the desktop/login screen.

Comment: @MarcoCiafa: I guessed. Since the weekday isn't included on my login screen I added `"%b %-e_%R"` (and the 'translation' of it).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 and I have determined that the clock has **only four** configuration options. Run `dconf-editor` under the current user and go to

**/ org / gnome / desktop / interface**

You have only the following configuration options:

| Option | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| clock-format | To display in **24h** or **12h** format |
| clock-show-date | To display abbreviated month name and day of the month in format **Mmm dd** |
| clock-show-seconds | To append seconds after minutes (**hh:mm:ss**) |
| clock-show-weekday | To prepend (three-letter) abbreviated name of the day of the week |

---

There is a Gnome extension called [**Clock Override**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/), that is supposed to customize more; however this extension does not look to have been updated for recent versions of GNOME.